# Crashed with Outlook 2019, not earlier?

Tags: vb6, outlook-redemption, outlook-2019

I have a 32-bit VB6 application that uses Outlook Redemption to send out e-mails. This program has worked fine up to Outlook 2016, but some of my customers are losing the ability to e-mail through my program when they either upgrade to 2019 or get auto-updated on their Office 365 subscription.

A simplified version of my code:

```
Private Sub cmdSendMessage_Click()
        Dim objSession As RDOSession
        Dim objOutbox As RDOFolder
        Dim objMessage As RDOMail
        Dim objRecipient As RDORecipient
        Dim strBody As String

100     On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

101     Set objSession = New RDOSession
102     objSession.Logon , , False, False

103     Set objOutbox = objSession.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderOutbox)
104     Set objMessage = objOutbox.Items.Add

105     Set objRecipient = objMessage.Recipients.Add(txtAddressTo.Text)
106     objRecipient.Resolve

107     strBody = "This is a test message--sent using Outlook Redemption." & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "Sent: " & Now & vbNewLine & _
            "Sent from Computer: " & GetThisComputerName

109     With objMessage
110         .Subject = "Test Message - Outlook Redemption"
111         .Body = strBody

112         .Send
113     End With 'objMessage

114     objSession.Logoff

115     MsgBox "Message sent.", vbOKOnly + vbInformation


ExitRoutine:
201    Set objRecipient = Nothing
202    Set objMessage = Nothing
203    Set objOutbox = Nothing
204    Set objSession = Nothing

210    Exit Sub

ErrorHandler:
    MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & Err.Description & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
        "Line " & Erl, vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error in Execution"
    Resume ExitRoutine

End Sub
```

I tried the program with the code above on a customer's machine running **Outlook 2019 MSO (16.0.12527.20260) 32-bit** with **Windows 10, 1909 (18363.535) 64-bit** and **32-bit Outlook Redemption 5.18**. The program immediately crashes without an error message when I click the button to send this e-mail.

Does Outlook Redemption work at all with VB6 and the newer versions of Outlook? If so, what do I need to change in my application to make it work?

Two errors appeared in the Application Event Log:

```
Faulting application name: RedemptionMail.exe, version: 1.0.0.0, time stamp: 0x5b995b5e
Faulting module name: RPCRT4.dll, version: 10.0.18362.476, time stamp: 0x7acb686b
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000461c6
Faulting process id: 0x1660
Faulting application start time: 0x01d60931c9abef20
Faulting application path: \\???\RedemptionMail.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
Report Id: 916c7e74-a3dd-440c-8759-23806d654b9d
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

and

```
Fault bucket 1285058706613227027, type 1
Event Name: APPCRASH
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0

Problem signature:
P1: RedemptionMail.exe
P2: 1.0.0.0
P3: 5b995b5e
P4: RPCRT4.dll
P5: 10.0.18362.476
P6: 7acb686b
P7: c0000005
P8: 000461c6
P9: 
P10: 

Attached files:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERDE85.tmp.mdmp
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERDEE4.tmp.WERInternalMetadata.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERDEF4.tmp.xml
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERDF04.tmp.csv
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\Temp\WERDF24.tmp.txt

These files may be available here:
\\?\C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportArchive\AppCrash_RedemptionMail.e_684bbff35d28781a9319f7f96316e4566e7d38f_ae0321e2_6f232be0-f6dd-46d3-bdbf-4f81e08f6760

Analysis symbol: 
Rechecking for solution: 0
Report Id: 916c7e74-a3dd-440c-8759-23806d654b9d
Report Status: 268435456
Hashed bucket: ca938f3d4eba0c8bd1d57215cb344e13
Cab Guid: 0
```

Comment: What is your version of Redemption? Please send an email to redemption (at) dimastr (dot) com and I will send you the debug version of Redemption.

Comment: Looking at the log of updates for Redemption (http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/history.htm) you need to upgrade your version to version 5.19.0.5238 or later.  I am running the latest version of Redemption (5.23.0.5664) and not having any issues with Outlook 2019.